# If a link to my site is sent by a visitor to their friend via email, is this counted as email traffic source in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, url, email, click-tracking

Let's say I have tracking set up on my website to capture traffic sources in GA.

If someone emails my site to a friend and they click on it, is this counted as an email source?

I know an email campaign delivered via a CMS would account for most email traffic, but how does this work when someone forwards an email with a link to your site?

Answer (score 1):

If someone emails a link to a friend - the raw url like `https://www.stitchfix.com/` - and the link is clicked, Google Analytics is unable to track the source.

Another twist is when you receive a marketing email containing a link like `https://www.stitchfix.com/?ref=email`. If this link is copied and shared with a friend over Slack or Skype, the tracking mechanism would record the friend's click as not coming from a chat application but coming from **email** due to the appended `ref=email`.

Lifewire.com has [a good piece](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-referrer-3468987) on HTTP Referrers (misspelled in spec as *referer*).

Comment: Typically if you want to track a link via parameters in Google Analytics you would use UTM parameters rather than the `ref=` parameter as you suggest.   GA automatically knows how to track the UTM parameters built with their [campaign URL builder tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/)

Comment: Agree with @StephenOstermiller. If you do not have these, and GA is unable to track the source, it falls into the "direct" bucket, which is like a catch-all